# Subclass Rack::Throttle

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems, rack, throttling

i am reading about Rack::Throttle and i want to change the default client identifier from an IP to somethng else. The documentation says it can be done

> The rate-limiting counters stored and maintained by Rack::Throttle are
>   keyed to unique HTTP clients.
>
> By default, HTTP clients are uniquely identified by their IP address
>   as returned by Rack::Request#ip. If you wish to instead use a more
>   granular, application-specific identifier such as a session key or a
>   user account name, you need only subclass a throttling strategy
>   implementation and override the #client_identifier method.

I have no clue where to add that in, here is my current subclass for another method. Does anybody know how to do this? https://github.com/datagraph/rack-throttle

```
    module Rack
  module Throttle
    class DailyRequests < Daily
      def allowed?(request)
        ## Insert rules
        super request
      end
    end

    class HourlyRequests < Hourly
      def allowed?(request)
        ## Insert rules
        super request
      end
    end

    class RequestInterval < Interval
      def allowed?(request)
        ## Insert rules
        super request
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: [Override the client_identifier method](https://github.com/datagraph/rack-throttle/blob/master/lib/rack/throttle/limiter.rb#L157), I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subclass one of the existing [rack-throttle](https://github.com/datagraph/rack-throttle) classes (probably either `Rack::Throttle::Interval` or `Rack::Throttle::TimeWindow`, whichever one more closely aligns with your needs) and override the `#client_identifier` method.

`#client_identifier` is passed one argument, `request`, which is a [Rack::Request](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Request.html) instance containing information passed in the incoming HTTP request and can be used to get information such as HTTP headers, cookies, path, and possibly other info depending on your app. The default implementation looks [like this](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Request.html):

```
# @param  [Rack::Request] request
# @return [String]
def client_identifier(request)
  request.ip.to_s
end
```

Here's an example of subclassing `Rack::Throttle::Interval` to match requests on a query parameter such as `?user_id=<id>`:

```
class UserThrottle < Rack::Throttle::Interval
  def client_identifier(request)
    request['user_id']
  end
end
```

which you could `use` in a Rack application with:

```
use UserThrottle, :min => 100
```

Notice you can still pass options like `:min` to the Rack `use` statement, since it is just subclassing the existing throttle classes. And adopting this in a Rails app would just involve calling `use` in your `application.rb` file (see [Rails on Rack](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html#configuring-middleware-stack)).